# How can I decompress a vector of deflated data with Boost?

Tags: c++, boost, compression, zlib, boost-iostreams

I have a vector that contains zlib-compressed (deflated) data. I would like to decompress it with Boost's `filtering_istream`. There is only one example on their site, which operates on a stream of data (as opposed to a vector that I have).

```
vector<char> compressed_buffer;
compressed_buffer.resize(cdh.length);
file.read(&compressed_buffer[0], cdh.length);

filtering_istream in;
in.push(zlib_decompressor());
in.push(something(compressed_data)); // what should "something" be?
```

I would like to get the uncompressed data as a vector as well. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about an [`array_source`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/array.html#array_source)?

```
in.push(array_source(&*compressed_data.begin(), &*compressed_data.end()));
```

Then use `boost::iostreams::copy` with a `std::insert_iterator` to push the result characters into a new vector.

Comment: Thanks, it worked greatly. For future reference, I constructed the inster_iterator with std::back_inserter.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer suggests `&*compressed_data.end()` which is undefined behavior because you dereference a past-the-end iterator. It only works by accident. The correct answer should use `data()` and `data() + size()` instead of `begin()` and `end()`.

```cpp
in.push(array_source(compressed_data.data(), compressed_data.data() + compressed_data.size()));
```