# Uncompressing zlib data using boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf trouble

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, stringstream

I'm trying to write a small class that will load the chunk data from part of a minecraft world file. I'm to the point where I have stored some data in a char array which was compressed with zlib and need to decompress it.

I'm trying to use the boost `filtering_streambuf` to do this.

```
char * rawChunk = new char[length - 1];

// Load chunk data


stringstream ssRawChunk(rawChunk);

boost::iostreams::filtering_istream in;

in.push(boost::iostreams::zlib_decompressor());
in.push(ssRawChunk);

stringstream ssOut;

boost::iostreams::copy(in, ssOut);
```

My problem is that `rawChunk` contains `null` data, so when coping data from `(char*) rawChunk` to `(stringstream) ssRawChunk`, it terminates at ~257 instead of the expected length 2154.

Is there any way to use filtering_streambuf without stringstream to allow for null data or is there a way to stop stringstream to not terminate on null data?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557555/how-can-i-decompress-a-vector-of-deflated-data-with-boost

Answer (score 0):

You should store `rawChunk` into `std::string` which allows null-characters.

Comment: I tried using a `string` first, then putting that into a `stringstream`, but it would still terminate at the first `null` value like in my first example. I'm trying the example given in the comment above, but am having trouble.