# Decompress file from Boost filtering_streambuf to std::vector<char>?

Tags: c++, boost, vector, deflate

I'm trying to decompress a file that was compressed using the DEFLATE algorithm and stuff it into a `vector<unsigned char>`. From the research I've done so far, it seemed like I could use a `boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf` and then use `boost::iostreams::copy()` to get it into a `boost::interprocess::basic_vectorstream<std::vector<unsigned char>>` and then pull the underlying vector out of the vectorstream. However, I'm getting a ton of compiler errors, starting with this:

```
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/copy.hpp: In function ‘std::streamsize boost::iostreams::detail::copy_impl(Source, Sink, std::streamsize) [with Source = boost::reference_wrapper<boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> >, Sink = boost::reference_wrapper<boost::interprocess::basic_vectorstream<std::vector<unsigned char> > >, std::streamsize = long int]’:
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/copy.hpp:245:79:   instantiated from ‘std::streamsize boost::iostreams::copy(Source&, Sink&, std::streamsize, typename boost::enable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<Source> >::type*, typename boost::enable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<Sink> >::type*) [with Source = boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input>, Sink = boost::interprocess::basic_vectorstream<std::vector<unsigned char> >, std::streamsize = long int, typename boost::enable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<Source> >::type = void, typename boost::enable_if<boost::iostreams::is_std_io<Sink> >::type = void]’
ValueFileReader.cpp:92:41:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/iostreams/copy.hpp:178:5: error: static assertion failed: "(is_same<src_char, snk_char>::value)"
```

The code I'm using is below (shortened up and doing "using namespace" for brevity here):

```
using namespace boost::iostreams;
using namespace boost::interprocess;

filtering_streambuf<input> in;
std::ifstream file(filename, std::ifstream::in);
in.push(zlib_decompressor());
in.push(file);

basic_vectorstream<std::vector<unsigned char>> vectorStream;
copy(in, vectorStream);
std::vector<unsigned char> chars(vectorStream.vector());
```

I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557555/how-can-i-decompress-a-vector-of-deflated-data-with-boost), but I wasn't sure if copying everything into a vector, then decompressing from the vector would be the most efficient way of going about it.

Is there a better way I can go about this, or do I have the right idea but some error in the code?

Comment: Does it build if you use `boost::interprocess::basic_vectorstream<std::vector<char>>`? It would help if you showed your code.

Comment: Updated my question with my code. Yes, it does compile without the `unsigned` in there... how come? Will I end up with things being read improperly if I'm using normal `char` instead of `unsigned char`?

Comment: @mtrewartha: No, you will be fine. `ifstream` etc. works on `char` data, so you need to use that. However, you can always cast the data to `unsigned char` later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `ifstream` and `filtering_streambuf` use `char` as their underlying character type, but your `basic_vectorstream` uses `unsigned char` as its value type. The Boost code has a static assertion requiring that these types be the same so that you don't get a spew of compiler errors if you use two different types that are not convertible.

Fortunately, the fix here is easy – change:

```
basic_vectorstream<std::vector<unsigned char>> vectorStream;
copy(in, vectorStream);
std::vector<unsigned char> chars(vectorStream.vector());
```

to:

```
basic_vectorstream<std::vector<char>> vectorStream;
copy(in, vectorStream);
std::vector<unsigned char> chars(
    vectorStream.vector().begin(),
    vectorStream.vector().end()
);
```

This is safe because `char` and `unsigned char` are guaranteed by the C++ standard to have the same object representation (§3.9.1/1).

---

Unrelated to your direct problem, but you also need to pass `std::ios::binary` to `file`'s constructor, otherwise you'll have corrupt data due to line-ending conversions.